# How do i set only first column to fill remaining space or trim its content if table is too small?

Tags: css, angular, autosize, column-width, mat-table

I am using material table component to display data in 3 columns. Lats 2 columns should have fixed width 50px. The first column should fill remaining space. If table is small, i 'dont want to display horizontal scrollbar. Text should be trimmed or wrapped (also when there are no spaces in it). How should i do it using css?

Comment: add your code showing your trouble if you expect efficient answers even if your issue  seems to be that obvious to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can reset the `table-layout` rule to `fixed` and set `width:100%;` to the table.

For `td`'s, `overflow:hidden` + `text-overflow` should morelike trim text.

test

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

table,
td {
  border: solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td+td {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</td>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 3 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> 1 kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</td>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 3 </td>
  </tr>
```

complementary ressources

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow
>
> The `text-overflow` CSS property sets how hidden overflow content is signaled to users. It can be clipped, display an ellipsis ('…'), or display a custom string.

---

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout
>
> The `table-layout` CSS property sets the algorithm used to lay out `<table>` cells, rows, and columns.